# Returning pointer from externally linked function crashes program

Tags: c, pointers, overflow

I have a function, bin2hexStr(), which converts a binary string into a hex string. When tested, it crashes my program when called 'for the last time'. It is successful for many function calls with smaller inputs tried before this example. But I'm not sure why it fails here. Additionally, if you remove Case 9 from below, it will fail on Case 8, where it will pass if executed as is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char bin2hexChar(char*);
int string_compare(char*, char*);
char* bin2hexStr(char*);

int main(void) {

    char* bin7 = "101110101111110000110001110010110011110100110101110110";
    char* bin25 = "100111010011101101011100111100011010111001000110100001101010";

    printf("Case 8: 101110101111110000110001110010110011110100110101110110 (54 bits):\n");
    printf("Expected Result: 2EBF0C72CF4D76\n");
    printf("Actual Result:   %s\n\n", bin2hexStr(bin7));

    printf("Case 9: 100111010011101101011100111100011010111001000110100001101010 (60 bits):\n");
    printf("Expected Result: 9D3B5CF1AE4686A\n");
    printf("Actual Result:   %s\n\n", bin2hexStr(bin25));

}

char* bin2hexStr(char* binStr) {

    char *paddedBin;
    int i,r;
    size_t loops;

    int count = 0;
    r = 4-strlen(binStr)%4;
    if(r!=4){
        loops = (strlen(binStr)+r)/4;
        paddedBin = (char *)malloc((loops+1)*sizeof(char));
        for(int j=0; j<r;++j)
            paddedBin[j] = '0';
        memcpy(paddedBin,&buffer[4-r],r);
        memcpy(&paddedBin[r],binStr,strlen(binStr)+1);
    }else{
        loops = ceil(strlen(binStr)/4);
        paddedBin = (char *)malloc((loops+1)*sizeof(char));
        memcpy(paddedBin,binStr,strlen(binStr)+1);
    }
    printf("Printing value of r (zeros to pad): %d\n", r);
    char *hexStr = (char *)malloc((loops)*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<(int)loops;i++){
        char *quartet = (char *)malloc((5)*sizeof(char));
        ++count;
        memcpy(quartet,&paddedBin[4*i],4);
        quartet[4]='\0';
        hexStr[i] = bin2hexChar(quartet);
        free(quartet);
    }

    hexStr[loops] = '\0';
    printf("Printing hex converted string: %s\n", hexStr);
    free(paddedBin);
    return hexStr;
}

char bin2hexChar(char* bin){

    static char hex_table[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                            '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    static char bin_table[16][5] = {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100",
                                "0101","0110", "0111", "1000", "1001",
                                "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110",
                                "1111"};

    int i;
    int k = 16;
    char hex;

    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        if (string_compare(bin,bin_table[i])==1) {
            hex = hex_table[i];
            break;  
        }
    }
    return hex;
}

int string_compare(char str1[], char str2[])
{
    int ctr=0;

    while(str1[ctr]==str2[ctr])
    {
        if(str1[ctr]=='\0'||str2[ctr]=='\0')
            break;
        ctr++;
    }
    if(str1[ctr]=='\0' && str2[ctr]=='\0')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Usually I have the functions in a separate file and link externally, but I have modified this to present a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable example.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: Upon more debugging, interesting behaviour ensues upon commenting out free(paddedBin). If free(paddedBin) stays uncommented, it fails upon returning of hexStr, as described. If free(paddedBin) is commented, it fails when producing the quartet for hex conversion in the for loop. Mind boggling.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to help you unless you provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Have you tried using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to see if that spots any problems for you?

Comment: functions are automatic extern in c, you dont need to do this extern char bin2hexChar(char*); just remove the extern from the function prototype

Comment: @kaylum I have provided a Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example. I would love if you could help me out.

Comment: As  I said. Can you run valgrind? I did and it points out very clear memory corruptions in your code.

Comment: @kaylum As I understand it, Valgrind is only for Linux. I have googled this and, no, I cannot :( you are the second person to recommend it.

Comment: Ok, then let me point out one error valgrind finds. It says this line is bad: `memmove(&paddedBin[r],binStr,strlen(binStr)+1);`. `paddBin` was allocated with size `strlen(binStr)+1`. So that line of code is a buffer overflow unless `r` is 0.

Comment: @kaylum Right. I modified so that paddBin is malloc'd with size (loops+1) and the issue persists. Is there another error that is suspect?

Comment: @kaylum I definitely agree there are memory problems. I thought perhaps it's suspect to be using memmove() with dyanmically allocated and non-dynamically allocated variabls, so I fixed that. Did not help.

Comment: While declaring function prototype u r declaring string compare parameters as pointers... While defining function downside you are using whole array as function parameter...is that correct :/ @Matt

Comment: @minigeek Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

fix and reduce like this(error check omitted)

```
char *bin2hexStr(const char *binStr){
    size_t loops, len = strlen(binStr);
    int r = len % 4;
    if(r)
        r = 4 - r;

    char *paddedBin = malloc(len + r + 1);//+1 for null-terminator
    memset(paddedBin, '0', r);//add padding to top
    memcpy(paddedBin + r, binStr, len + 1);
    loops = (len + r) / 4;
    char *hexStr = malloc(loops + 1);//+1 for NUL
    for(size_t i = 0; i < loops; i++){
        hexStr[i] = bin2hexChar(paddedBin + i * 4);
    }
    hexStr[loops] = '\0';
    free(paddedBin);
    return hexStr;
}

char bin2hexChar(const char *bin){
    static char hex_table[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                            '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        k = k * 2 + *bin++ - '0';//calculate index
    }
    return hex_table[k];
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain this solution? When I copy and paste it into the functions in my post, yes, it works. However, when I replace the contents of my function files for each externally linked function, the result is null. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Matt Change prototype to `char bin2hexChar(const char*);
char *bin2hexStr(const char*);`  I think there is a problem with your code.